# Rails/MYSQL - Find all with no association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have an Employee model and a Shift model. Employees have many shifts and shifts have a date.

I want to be able to select all employees that are available for a given date i.e. select all employees where no associated shifts exists for a given date.

I can select all employees without a shift like this:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users
LEFT JOIN shifts ON users.id = shifts.user_id
WHERE shifts.user_id IS NULL;
```

But this is not date specific.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN shifts ON users.id = shifts.user_id 
    AND shifts.Date = @SomeDate
WHERE shifts.user_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: All existing shifts have a date and a user_id, so this returns an empty set.